# different query results in postgresql staging and production

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

consider below query

```
   select ...
    (
      select ... from 
         (
            select * from trips where deviceid=ANY('{22}'::int[]) order by startts
         ) as sortedtrips group by deviceid
    ) as V 
    right join devices D on D.deviceid=V.deviceid 
    left join mostrecent M on M.deviceid=D.deviceid 
    left join v_auto_odometer DD on DD.deviceid=M.deviceid 
    where D.deviceid=ANY('{22}'::int[])
```

It used to run fine in both my production as staging environment.
Suddenly this query no longer runs in staging, but does run in production.

The culprit seems to be the last "where" clause

```
... where D.deviceid=ANY('{22}'::int[])
```

which results into

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: ""
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""
SQL state: 22P02
```

Changing this to

```
D.deviceid=22
```

resolves the issue (but note that a very similar where clause is still available in the query and does not give problems).

I have absolutely no idea what happened, and why the query is no longer working. it seems related to the specific postgres environment, which differ in the subversion

```
staging:PostgreSQL 9.3.5
production:PostgreSQL 9.3.4
```

I really need to use the ANY statement (as the above query is a mere example. The real query uses an actual array of id's.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What datatype is `deviceid`?

Comment: It sounds as if it is a `varchar`` and there is an implicit data type conversion going on

Comment: Please put line-breaks in the query so that we can read it.  Also, while both databases are 9.3, what minor versions are they?  If one is 9.3.0 and the other is 9.3.5, I can think of some bug fixes which might affect this ...

Comment: Check the log to see what query is really being issued. In Fedora it is at `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log/postgresql-Fri.log`. Post it.

Comment: NOTE: the `order by startts` in the subquery makes no sense. and repeating the `D.deviceid=ANY('{22}'::int[])` condition in the mainquery does not seem to make sense either , since all four tables are already joined on the deviceid - field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments.

In the end, the problem was related to a data mismatch between staging and prodution. A null value in a specific column caused the issue in staging.

Postgres was not helping me with the specific error messages.